# Scrabble computer version that uses the new dictionary? (OSPD4/OTCWL2)

Tags: scrabble, computers

Is there a version of the computer Scrabble game that uses the new dictionary (not really new anymore, came out in 2006)?  I know about [ISC](http://www.isc.ro), but we're looking for something that my technophobic mother-in-law can use to play against her computer.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Facebook Scrabble](http://apps.facebook.com/ea_scrabble_closed) uses the new dictionary.

This can also be played via your iPhone (connects to the same same servers, so players on different platforms may play).  The iPhone version has single-player.

Quadplex is another site that hosts Scrabble.